# java logging : multiple small file vs one big

Tags: java, performance, unix, logging, log4j

Using log4j on Unix, which Appender would perform the best to write 1000Meg :

1) Using RollingFileAppender writing 10 file of 100 Meg

or

2) Using a FileAppender and writing a single 1000Meg file

In other words, using java on unix, does the size matter?

Thank you

Comment: the size does matter but not this case, you are appending, not reading the file, so even fragmentation is not an issue.

Comment: I think this largely depends on the tool(s) used for viewing the log(s) and which setup is easier to maintain -- performance of the log "write" itself is likely only a secondary consideration (see bestsss's comment) although making sure not to run out of disk is something to keep in mind :-) It may make sense to break into day or week or whatnot -- irrelevant of file size.

Comment: @pst, my fav. tool is called 'less' :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There no Java-side performance difference between writing to a small file or writing to a large file.  There *might* be a *small* difference at the OS level when a file gets big enough that an extra level of index blocks is required (FS dependent), but it is probably not worth worrying about.

There will be a performance cost in implementing the file rolling behavior.  The appender has to:

- test / remember how big the file is,
- close the current one,
- rename it,
- open a new file.

My gut feeling is that this is not likely to be significant.  (However, it would be worth **measuring** to see if the performance impact should be a concern.  Also, you should probably ask yourself if you are not doing **too much logging**.)

You have to compare all of the above against the advantages of file rolling:

- Having a bounded size on log files means that your logging won't fill the disk, causing problems for the application and potentially others on the same machine.
- Smaller log files can make it easier / quicker to do searches for events at specific times.  (Running `less` on a 1000Mb file can be painful ...)

Answer (score 0):

They'll both easily write 1000MB files. I don't see why they should perform differently.

You do need the `RollingFileAppender` though in order to set the total maximum size that the log file(s) can reach. Otherwise you may run out of hard disk space, assuming that you application has got traffic.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's always preferable to use small files than large files because they are more manageable. Also, consider that with large files you may have problems in the case of file-system full because of the risk of having to remove the log file when the process is up and running to free up disk space.