# Small logs vs big logs : logging via Java

Tags: java, logging

My use case : 
In an hour, I get 10000 customer requests. We create an hourly log file. Each customer log is of 5K, i.e. hourly log is 50M + some system logged data. We use grepping for post log analysis and log4j for writing the logs.

Question :
Is is better to create a log file per customer, or dump all customer logs in one large hourly file along with other system related logs.

Looking for :

An answer, which covers (in priority order ) :

1. Performance : Overhead while creating the log (i.e. runtime log4j performance)?
2. Scalability : Suppose I start getting 1 M customers in an hour?
3. Storage Management : Multiple small files are easy to maintain or one big file at OS level?
4. Log analysis : Is grepping a large log file is better OR finding a file in OS is better?

I have seen this link, [java logging : multiple small file vs one big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980918/java-logging-multiple-small-file-vs-one-big), this scenario is little different, it questions breaking into pieces based on size, while I talk about breaking based on some unique identifier.

Comment: I feel your question is a bit too broad, but my two cents favors having a single log file for all customers.  If something breaks in your app, you will find it very handy to a have a single point of reference.  A single log file would also afford you the ability to see _which_ customers are being affected, on one sheet of paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Performance : Overhead while creating the log (i.e. runtime log4j performance)?

More files are slower to write and slower to read if you need to scan them all.

If you need to read just one, it's much faster.

> Scalability : Suppose I start getting 1 M customers in an hour?

1 Million files is a lot but either solution can work.

> Storage Management : Multiple small files are easy to maintain or one big file at OS level?

More files are harder to manage, but 1 million isn't that much these days unless you have a spinning disk in which case, it could perform very badly.

> Log analysis : Is grepping a large log file is better OR finding a file in OS is better?

If you only have to deal with one file it's better.

BTW You can have a combination such as one file for each digits e.g. all user id ending in 0, and another for those ending in 1.  This allows you to partition the data and control the number of files.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am satisfied with last 3 answers. For first question, I am not planning to scan, just writing. My question is, if we switch filesper request on server, does it affect loggers performance, or keeping same file throughout the life of server is better.

Comment: @ShrotTripathi I wouldn't create more files than you need to. On a spinning disk each file adds about 10 ms. But if you need to search across 1 million files this can take hours.

Comment: I am asking from code point of view, means does java logger have overhead of creating different log files, or it doesnot matter to logger classes, if we write in the same file. It would help, if you can answer this.Any way I got the gist and idea of what i need to use.

Comment: @ShrotTripathi for the logger library it is much simpler to have one log file (or a rotating log file)