# log4j2 multiple log files performance vs one big log file

Tags: java, spring, performance, log4j, log4j2

Working on a huge Java/Spring monolith app. We use log4j2 for logging. We have very few log files because our chief architect does not accept creating more log files for separate things, because a) he "knows" that every new file will impact performance negatively (writing to many files in a monolith will impact performance much more than writing to single one or the few we have) b) we use a log aggregator service in production and CI that can be used to filter out/sort all logs, and he considers that this is the way to go all time.

Problem is, though, that using so few log files makes a mess in the actual logs and without using any tools to sort and filter, developers usually look into those files only for errors and not understanding the flow or anything else, thus more time spent actually debugging app than adding logs or going through them. We do not have log aggregators for development machines obviously as it is a paid service for production/CI only.

Personally I do not like the idea of having a mess in the log files the way we have and consider it a mistake as it is hard to understand something in there if you open the logs with Notepad++ only, for example.

I have found the answer [logging big file small files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980918/java-logging-multiple-small-file-vs-one-big) which somehow answers part of my question from one point of view, but still, does anyone have any idea if there is any issue with multiple files from performance perspective, or shall I spend time actually trying to prove one idea or the other?

Comment: It is a hard question to answer. 1st of all, don't use Notepad++, use specific tooling like github.com/variar/klogg 2nd, typically a log is a mess of user access info (for audit) and debug-related info. One single log isn't the best way to address both problems. At least audit-related info should go to specific storage (nosql db, etc) to support analytical processing, not just to a plain text file. I'd also like to share this https://habr-com.translate.goog/ru/company/oleg-bunin/blog/468535/?_x_tr_sl=ru&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=ru as food for thought to cleanup your logging

Comment: The key idea is "to work no longer as with logs, but as with useful data - such work is more transparent and more convenient"

Comment: @AnatolyG we have separate logs for audit, rest, sessions, async tasks. But let's say, there are less than 20 categories of logs total, and most of them are infra. Functionality logs, though, are basically non-existent. All different big functionalities in the app go into app.log, and if you are debugging or trying to figure out the complete flow for a functionality, it simply is impossible, as in between interfere lots of other logs from core or utility services, potentially from different users across the whole system. Local understanding what is in this file is pain.

Comment: "if you are debugging or trying to figure out the complete flow for a functionality, it simply is impossible". A: "The correct way is to throw them away and forget...use a suitable tool like sentry.io". I'm sure it's too radical for your "chief architect", but he/she may just think about it. There is no way for a messy-looking plain text file to be collected and analyzed other than ELK or something like that with significant postprocessing efforts.